# Configuration file for NetworkManager in Ubuntu Core

Tags: wireless, network-manager, configuration, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to figure out where to place the configuration files for wireless networks for NetworkManager in Ubuntu Core.

Anyone having an idea? I've looked through /snap/NetworkManager and /home/user/snap/NetworkManager, but none of the folders inside these looks familiar to the folder structure from within /etc/NetworkManager on a server distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/index) for network management on Ubuntu Core says this about it:

> By default network management on Ubuntu Core is handled by systemd's [networkd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.service.html) and [netplan](https://launchpad.net/netplan). While NetworkManager has some support to handle netplan configuration files, Ethernet support is disabled by default and has to be turned on explicitly to avoid conflicts with existing network configuration.

The link to networkd has this to say:

> **Configuration Files**
>
> The configuration files are read from the files located in the system network directory `/usr/lib/systemd/network`, the volatile runtime network directory `/run/systemd/network` and the local administration network directory `/etc/systemd/network`.

The link to netplan has this to say:

> **YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends (NetworkManager, networkd)**
>
> netplan reads network configuration from `/etc/nplan/*.yaml` which are written by administrators, installers, cloud image instantiations, or other OS deployments. During early boot it then generates backend specific configuration files in `/run` to hand off control of devices to a particular networking daemon.

So take your pick from any of the listed configuration files.